# Get all child elements disregarding namespace URIs

Tags: java, xml, xom

Sometimes I have an XML:

```
<resource 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test.com/resource http://test.com/schema/resource 
    xmlns="http://www.test.com/resource"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...
</resource>
```

and sometimes w/o the namespace URIs, i.e.

```
<resource>
...
</resource>
```

How to make fetch all child elements of `resource` no matter the namespace URIs?

I am using `nu.xom.Element` to handle elements and I build a `nu.xom.Document` this way:

```
nu.xom.Builder parser = new nu.xom.Builder();
return parser.build( new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes()) );
```

Comment: How are you currently parsing the file?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't indicated whether `<resource>` is the root element. If it is then it's trivial to find. if not, find all  `<resource>` elements by:

```
Nodes resourceNodes = yourDoc.query("//*[local-name()='resource']");
for (int i = 0; i < resourceNodes .size(); i++) {
    Element resource = (Element) resourceNodes .get(i);
    Elements childElements = resource.getChildElements();
    // .. etc
}
```

or directly:

```
Nodes resourceChildren = yourDoc.query("//*[local-name()='resource']/*");
```